# What is the most dangerous being in the Forbidden Forest?

Tags: harry-potter

I have used the word being because I don't know the extent of creatures and their classifications that inhabit the Forbidden Forest.

Comment: How do you define "dangerous"?

Comment: Defining dangerous as a threat to humans

Comment: you're just as dead if you are hit by centaur arrow as eaten by acromantula as by a wolf

Comment: Give that as you may, what is the most easily provoked inhabitent in the forbidden forest by humans?

Comment: - all of them. It's like a mini-Australia :)

Comment: @dvk - What happens if you're hit by a wolf riding an acromantula, fired by a centaur?

Comment: Or, what if you get stabbed by a unicorn wielding Grawp riding a Thestral?

Comment: I see a close vote for this question being opinion based, which it normally would be, except that in the Harry Potter canon we have _Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them_, which offers a classification (as evidenced by the answers given).

Answer (score 7):

- [Acromantulas](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Acromantula) (classification [XXXXX](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ministry_of_Magic_Classification))
- Grawp (full grown but "runt" giant)

There isn't enough info in the question to decide which of the 2 are more "dangerous". The former have many many family members. The latter is, well, a giant. Neither one is shown to either fight another, nor compete in how dangerous they are to humans (by killing large amounts of those)

For a full list of inhabitants:

- http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Forest#Inhabitants
- http://www.hp-lexicon.org/hogwarts/castle/forest.html

The rest of inhabitants clearly aren't as dangerous:

- None of the other non-sentient beasts classified as XXXXX classification by the Ministry
- Sentient ones who aren't classified, aren't implied to be as murderous as giants (e.g. trolls who Hagrid supposedly wrestled as schoolchild clearly are smaller/weaker - Hagrid as a kid wouldn't "wrestle" with a giant; and centaurs even less dangerous size wise, but they can of course kill you just as easy with a bow and arrow).

Comment: Can you give reference to this? Or is it an opinion? DVK

Comment: @liamtomkins - reference for which specific fact? List of beasts? That's compiled from books 1-7. Relative dangers? Mostly same, though acrumantula also from Fantastic Beasts.

Comment: "Ease of provocation" is also clearly subjective as well. Umbridge provoked the Centaurs with ease, while civil people like Ron, Harry, and Hermione had no problems with them at all.

Comment: @krillgar "no problems with them at all" isn't close to true; at least some of the centaurs were more than happy to murder them on several occasions in the last three books.

Comment: Good point. Sorry, it's been too long. Regardless, the fact that they showed them respect allowed them to fare far better than Umbridge.

Answer (score 5):

In *Philosopher's Stone*, the kids have a conversation with Filch:

> ‘The Forest?’ [Draco] repeated, and he didn’t sound quite as cool as
>   usual. ‘We can’t go in there at night – there’s all sorts of things in
>   there – werewolves, I heard.’
>   Neville clutched the sleeve of Harry’s robe and made a choking
>   noise.
>   ‘That’s your lookout, isn’t it?’ said Filch, his voice cracking with
>   glee. ‘Should’ve thought of them werewolves before you got in
>   trouble, shouldn’t you?’
>   <sub>*Philosopher's Stone* - page 182 - Bloomsbury - chapter fifteen, *The Forbidden Forest*</sub>

I noted that Filch didn't exactly confirm the presence of werewolves in the forest; he merely chastises the kids that if they didn't want to deal with scary creatures they shouldn't have broken the rules in the first place. I point this out because in the movie *Philosopher's Stone*, Filch says, after Draco complains about werewolves, "Oh, there's more than werewolves in there, to be sure. Nighty night." (Paraphrase) The movie implies the forest has werewolves; the books do not definitely affirm this.

There are dangerous creatures in the Forbidden Forest, for sure: Acromantulas (XXXXX), Centaurs (XXXX), the Phoenix, if Fawkes is so inclined to visit the forest here and there (XXXX), Unicorns (XXXXX), *possibly* werewolves (XXXXX), and winged horses, such as Thestrals (XX - XXXXX). This is information is taken from *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* -- I looked through the book myself. While there are many more (XXXX) and (XXXXX) creatures in the wizarding world, only those listed would be found in Hogwarts' Forbidden Forest. Note that while Grawp, half-giant, temporarily resided in the forest; however, *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* doesn't list giants.

In *Order of the Phoenix*, Hagrid says:

> ‘Anyway,’ [Hagrid] said, breathing a little more heavily than usual,
>   ‘since then the other centaurs’ve bin livid with me, an’ the trouble
>   is they’ve got a lot of influence in the Forest ... cleverest creatures
>   in here.’
>   <sub>*Order of the Phoenix* - page 605 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirty, *Grawp*</sub>

I think when you have a group of (XXXX) and (XXXXX) creatures, it's going to be hard to choose one as the most dangerous -- they are obviously all extremely dangerous in their own way. According to *FBAWTFT*, the Nudu is the most dangerous magical creature, but it lives only Africa. Professor Lupin demonstrated how dangerous a werewolf is; Aragog and company showed the dangers of the Acromantula. We know Fawkes' powers in a different, more positive way. Canon hasn't shown us if/why unicorns are actually dangerous, despite their (XXXXX) classification.

Centaurs, however, are sentient, and sentience combined with physical strength and a propensity toward violence is a very dangerous combination. The other creatures act instinctively; the centaur can plan and execute plots and are lethal creatures. I lean toward the centaurs.

I suppose it could be argued that for those moments, off and on, that Quirrell and Voldemort were in the forest preying on the unicorns, they *might* be considered the most dangerous, but, technically, are they a "creature"? I can't say for certainty that they were.

Answer (score 1):

Most easily provoked?

The Acromantulas, hands down: you don't need to do *anything* to provoke them - they'll attack if given any opportunity to do so, because humans are natural prey to them.

None of the other creatures known to be in the forest seem likely to attack unless you behave disrespectfully to them.  Of course, that assumes that you've paid enough attention in Care of Magical Creatures to know what sort of respect each species expects. :-)

Note that I'm explicitly excluding werewolves from consideration, because I don't believe there were any in the forest.  (This is because, if the forest couldn't contain them, they'd be attacking students outside the forest all the time, but if the forest could contain them, Dumbledore would not have needed the Whomping Willow and the Shrieking Shack to keep the other students safe from Lupin when he was at Hogwarts.)